# Incorrect syntax near '00'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new in asp & sql server. I have a problem in sql query.

```
string obal ;
        decimal _obalss = 0;
        decimal obalss = 0;
        sconnection c = new sconnection();
        string cus_id = Session["cusid"].ToString();
        DateTime maxdate = DateTime.Parse(fromdt.Text, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
        string mdate = maxdate.ToString();
        string query_sl = "select sum(amount) as amount from sale where cusid = " + cus_id + " and invdate < " + maxdate + " group by cusid"; 
        SqlDataReader dr = c.reader(query_sl);
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            decimal.TryParse(dr["amount"].ToString(), out _obalss);
            obalss = _obalss;
        }
        else
        {
            obalss = 0;
        }
            dr.Close();
            dr.Dispose();
```

Comment: Quick note: this has *nothing* to do with ASP.NET and *everything* to do with SQL.

Comment: Put breakpoint and see which query is generated into the query_sl string variable, post it here so we can see which query actually was executed

Answer (score 11):

```
 string query_sl = "select sum(amount) as amount from sale where cusid = " + cus_id + " and invdate < " + maxdate + " group by cusid";
```

`maxdate` is a date, you have to put it in single quotes. Even better you **should** use parameterized SQL queries otherwise you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. How about something like this:

```
string query_sl = "select sum(amount) as amount from sale where cusid = @CUSID and invdate < @MAXDATE group by cusid"; 
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query_sl, c))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CUSID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = cus_id;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MAXDATE", SqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = maxdate;
    ...
}
```

Comment: At least +1 for parameterised queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
string query_sl = "select sum(amount) as amount from sale where cusid = " + cus_id + " and invdate < '" + maxdate + "' group by cusid";
```

Notice the single quotes around maxdate...